# JBPM - difference between aync and exclusive actions

Tags: jbpm

What is the difference between JPDL continue="async" and continue="exclusive"?

async means job executors [whether from same or different machine] pick up and execute these jobs.

What does exclusive mean? Description in JBPM doc is hard to parse.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of jBPM are you using? I don't remember the continue="exclusive" being in 3.2.6
Cheers